# What does a _ mean in block arguments?

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if somebody could please explain to me what the dash place holder does?

```
def remove_every_other(arr)
  arr.select.with_index { |_,idx| idx.even? }
end
```

Comment: It is simply a common way in Ruby to indicate that the first variable will not be used within the block. Note that there is nothing special about the `_` in this case, it is just a convention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some sense, this is just another parameter like any other. There is no difference between the parameter named `_` and the parameter named `idx`. They are both parameters like any other parameter.

So, in some sense, there is nothing special about `_`: it's a name like any other name and could just as well be named `foo` or `bar` or `baz`.

However, that is not *quite* true: `_` *is* treated special by the Ruby language. More precisely, *any local variable name or parameter name starting with `_`* is treated special by the Ruby language.

In many communities, the identifier `_` or identifiers starting with `_` are used to signify that something is being *deliberately ignored*. And this is also the usage in the Ruby community.

In order to support this usage of `_` for ignored variables or parameters, the Ruby language treats local variables and parameters starting with `_` special in two ways:

## Unused local variable warnings

Ruby will generate warnings for unused local variables:

```ruby
a = 42
b = 42

b
```

will generate "warning: assigned but unused variable - a".

However, if I rename the variable to `_a` or `_`, the warning will be suppressed:

```ruby
_a = 42
_ = 42
b = 42

b
```

## Duplicate parameter `SyntaxError`

Using the same name twice in the same parameter list (in a method parameter list, block parameter list, and lambda literal parameter list) is a `SyntaxError`:

```ruby
def foo(a, a) end
# duplicated argument name (SyntaxError)
```

```ruby
foo {|a, a|}
# duplicated argument name (SyntaxError)
```

```ruby
-> (a, a) {}
# duplicated argument name (SyntaxError)
```

but `_a` or `_` are valid:

```ruby
def foo(_a, _a, _, _) end
foo {|_a, _a, _, _|}
-> (_a, _a, _, _) {}
```

## Last result in IRb

There is a *third* usage of `_` specifically in [IRb](https://github.com/ruby/irb) which has nothing to do with the above: in IRb, [the local variable `_` is automatically assigned the value of the last expression](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Session+variables) that was evaluated in the current IRb session. But this is *purely* a feature of IRb and has nothing to do with Ruby.

## Treatment in linters / style-checkers / static analyzers

The default rulesets in many linters, style-checkers, and static analyzers forbid unused parameters and local variables, on the assumption that this usually indicates a typo, a programming error, or leftover code from a refactoring. Similar to Ruby itself, they usually *do* allow this for variables and parameters starting with `_`.

This has nothing to do with the Ruby language itself, though, it is a matter of the Ruby community, more precisely, the developers of those tools following the majority usage within the community.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, underscore will allow you to skip elements you do not need.

In other cases _ equals last output.

```
$ irb
>> 2*3
=> 6
>> _ + 7
=> 13
>> _
=> 13
```